# Bluebeam w/ 4 Radio Groups

Tags: javascript, pdfstamper

I'm working with a user who uses Bluebeam Extreme and they want a stamp modified with 4 radio groups. I opened the JavaScript file he sent me and added the 4 radio groups but now the stamp dialog box is no longer appearing like it use to. Now on Bluebeam's website it does say "The Submittal Status Stamp is only intended to operate with one radioGroup. If you attempt to add a second radioGroup, the stamp will no longer function properly. Of course if he uses the original it works fine. Just want to make sure my code looks fine since I'm sort of new to JavaScript

The image below shows the Stamp Dialog Box that does not appear.
[Stamp Dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhbBb.png)

Here is the original Stamp Code

```
var builder = 
{
    // These map to Text Fields in the Stamp
    textBoxes :
    [
        { field:"ProjectNo", description:"CESO Project #:", default:function() { return ""; } },
        { field:"ReviewedBy", description:"Reviewed by:", default:function() { return Collab.user; } },     
        { field:"Date", description:"Date:", default:function() 
            {  
                var curDate = new Date();
                return (curDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + curDate.getDate() + "/" + curDate.getFullYear();
            } 
        },  
        { field:"PhaseNo", description:"CESO Phase #:", default:function() { return ""; } },
                              { field:"Direct", description:"Expense Type Direct (X):", default:function() { return ""; } },
                              { field:"Reimbursable", description:"Expense Type Reimbursable (X):", default:function() { return ""; } },
                              { field:"PriorInvoice", description:"Billing Round Prior Invoice (X):", default:function() { return ""; } },
                              { field:"InvoiceNo", description:"Prior Invoice #:", default:function() { return ""; } },
                              { field:"NextBillingRound", description:"Billing Round Next (X):", default:function() { return ""; } },
                              { field:"Yes", description:"Fully Executed Yes (X):", default:function() { return ""; } },
                              { field:"No", description:"Fully Executed No (X):", default:function() { return ""; } },
                              { field:"Notes", description:"Notes/Comments:", default:function() { return ""; } }
    ],
        // This maps to a Radio Group in the PDF named 'Status'
    radioGroup : "Status",  
    radioButtons :
    [
        // value maps to the 'Choice' of each radio button in the group, description will show on the dialog
        { value:"Approved", description:"Approved" },   
        { value:"Rejected", description:"Rejected" }
    ],
    radioErrorMsg : "Please select a status",

}
```

Here is the Updated Stamp Code

```
var builder = 
{
    textBoxes: [
      { field: "ProjectNo", description: "CESO Project #:", default: function() { return ""; } },
      { field: "ReviewedBy", description: "Reviewed by:", default: function() { return Collab.user; } },
      { field: "Date", description: "Date:", default: function() {
          var curDate = new Date();
          return (curDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + curDate.getDate() + "/" + curDate.getFullYear();
        }
      },
      { field: "PhaseNo", description: "CESO Phase #:", default: function() { return ""; } },
      { field: "InvoiceNo", description: "Prior Invoice #:", default: function() { return ""; } },
      { field: "Yes", description: "Fully Executed Yes (X):", default: function() { return ""; } },
      { field: "No", description: "Fully Executed No (X):", default: function() { return ""; } },
      { field: "Notes", description: "Notes/Comments:", default: function() { return ""; } }
    ],
    radioGroups: [
      {
        name: "Status", // This maps to a Radio Group in the PDF named 'Status'
        choices: [
        // value maps to the 'Choice' of each radio button in the group, description will show on the dialog
          { value: "Approved", description: "Approved" },
          { value: "Rejected", description: "Rejected" }
        ],
        radioErrorMsg: "Please select a status"
      },
      {
        name: "ExpenseType", // This maps to a Radio Group in the PDF named 'ExpenseType'
        choices: [
          { value: "Direct", description: "Direct" },
          { value: "Reimbursable", description: "Reimbursable" }
        ],
        radioErrorMsg: "Please select an expense type"
      },
      {
        name: "BillingRound", // This maps to a Radio Group in the PDF named 'BillingRound'
        choices: [
          { value: "PriorInvoice", description: "Prior Invoice" },
          { value: "NextBillingRound", description: "Next Billing Round" }
        ],
        radioErrorMsg: "Please select a billing round"
      },
      {
        name: "FullyExecuted", // This maps to a Radio Group in the PDF named 'FullyExecuted'
        choices: [
          { value: "Yes", description: "Yes" },
          { value: "No", description: "No" }
        ],
        radioErrorMsg: "Please select an option for fully executed"
      }
    ]
  };
```